# How to use gameObject from one script in another?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script that finds objects using a ray

```
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mainMaterial;
            GameObject objects = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
```

how to pass the found game object to another script to use?

```
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
                {
                    obj = ?;
                }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a static variable top of the first script when you find gameobject with raycast set the variable and then you can use in second script. This is just one of the several ways.
In first script create:

```
 public static GameObject object;

   
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mainMaterial;
        object = hit.collider.gameObject;
    }
```

And second script you can call it like that:

```
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                obj = firstScript.object;
            }
```

Comment: error CS0176: Member 'DragElement.objj' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: выдает вот такую ошибку

Comment: it is not possible to use the variable name "object"

Comment: renamed to class name, everything started, but when applying the object, it gives the following error -

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ChangeMatCommand.ExecuteCommand () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts Undo/ChangeMatCommand.cs:28)
CommandManager.ExecuteCommand (IAction action) (at Assets/Resources/Scripts Undo/CommandManager.cs:14)
ClickManager.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts Undo/ClickManager.cs:52)

Comment: You shouldn't use `object` as name .. and the field shouldn't be `static` ...

Answer (score 0):

You should save the object in a public GameObject which can be called from another script. Lets assume we have 3 objects in our scene. Object 1 is the object being detected by object2 through a raycast. So object2 finds object1 and saves it like:

```
public GameObject rayHitObject;
// blah blah blah
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mainMaterial;
        rayHitObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
    }
```

Now object3 can get that object from object2 by calling `object2.GetComponent<otherscript>().rayHitObject`

Edit: Make sure `public GameObject rayHitObject;` is right below your class definition, this is how you save public variables, IE `public class otherscript : MonoBehaviour`.